# Calling an infinite loop in a Java applet

Tags: java, loops, applet, freeze, destroy

I have developed a graphics library and to show its capabilities, I developed a simple "Pong" clone. I created a new applet that runs the game, and being new to Java I put the game's loop in the paint function. I am seeking to migrate the loop to a different function so that it still runs but destroy() calls respond.

Is this possible in a Java Applet? I do not want to hang the applet at any stage, e.g. init(), paint(), destroy(). Should I try a different approach?
Thanks!

Here are the links to my code:

Actual game: http://pastebin.com/vr541pnE

Graphics Library: http://pastebin.com/5MMWqthf

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to create a separate method `run()` containing your main loop.

According to this javadoc [Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html) you may use `start()` and `stop()` to start or stop the game main loop.

- `start()` would call `run()`.
- `stop()` would set a boolean like you do in `destroy()` to stop the main loop.
- `init()` informs the applet that it has been loaded into the system, there you may create any object that should persist outside of the game loop.
- `destroy()` informs the applet it should destroy any resources that it has allocated, basically used to destroy objects created by `init()`.

Your simple game may run like this :

1. Browser load the applet.
2. Browser call `init()` -> the applet is loaded, create objects and load resources.
3. Browser call `start()` -> the applet start executing, call the main loop.
4. Applet run the main loop called by `start()`.
5. Browser or Game call `stop()` -> end or pause the main loop.
6. Browser call `destroy()` -> the applet may destroy any created object.

You will find more detail in the [Applet Javadoc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html)